# How to make my converting millis to work with big numbers

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Millls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter milliseconds: ");
    long millis= sc.nextLong();

    System.out.println(convertMillis(millis));

    }

    public static String convertMillis(long millis){

        long s = (millis / 1000) % 60;
        long m = (millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;   
        long hh = (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        String time = String.format("%d:%d:%d",hh,m,s);
        return time;
    }
}
```

I need to specifically do convert mills (555550000) to return a string 154:19:10. Please it is different than the other questions. I had try %02: but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking the modulo 24 of the hours. So you'll always end up with hours between 0 and 23 inclusive. Remove the modulo and you'll get the expected result:

```
long hh = (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60))
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) Api in Java. It had direct methods to convert from one time unit to another.

Sample usage:

```
    long s = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(555550000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    long m = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(555550000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    long hh = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(555550000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```